# How to add firebase to flutter app?? (object C? swift?)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'd like to add firebase to my flutter application. When I was developing another flutter app before, also at that time I used firebase, It was fine. However, in this time It doesn't work well. I think It's because recently flutter changed the IOS part from object-c to swift.

Below is my `AppDelegate.m` file.

```swift
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"

@import Firebase;

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
  [FIRApp configure];

  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  //return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  return YES;
}

@end
```

I got this error message.

```
    path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
6.3.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000012] Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.
6.3.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
6.3.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b98bde __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff503b5b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b98a1c +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
    3   Runner                              0x000000010e2f5feb +[FIRApp configure] + 555
    4   Runner                              0x000000010e2f5738 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 120
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4715994f -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 232
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4715b2e7 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDe<…>
```

And `pubspec.yaml`.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  firebase_core: ^0.2.5  # add dependency for Firebase Core
```

How can I solve this problem???

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Firebase project for your application? You need to download GoogleService-Info.plist from firebase console and add it to XCode workspace.